# Как скомпилить boost 1.55 ??

Tags: mingw, boost, build, c++

Привет всем.
Я скачал буст и MinGW но как мне собрать буст и подкючить в VS 2013?
Я Знаю команду :`bootstrap.bat mingw`но она не работает, пишет что нет такой команды. 
Не могу понять как подключить gcc что бы использовать его для сборки.
P.S. Если я собираю через майкрософт то у меня где  8 ошибок с кодом C3861! :(
Как быть?

Comment: судя по тексту Вашего вопроса, Вы никак не можете определиться.

Если Вы скомпилируете с помощью MinGW, то результат можно будет использоваться только с MinGW. Что бы использовать с студией, нужно ее компилятором.

Правда можно использовать студию только как редактор, но это как то странно.

А предварительно скомпилированное Вам не подходит?

Answer (score 3):

1. Скачайте boost с сайта [boost.org](http://www.boost.org).
2. В распакованном архиве откройте `index.html`, верхняя левая ссылка — Getting started, следуйте инструкциям.
3. После этого нужно добавить `"путь\до\места\установки\boost\boost_1_46_1"` к списку *Additional Include Directories* в настройках проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Сборка для MinGW:

1) Скачать исходники [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), распаковать куда хочется.

2) Скачать MinGW.

3) Создать файл env.bat* следующего содержания (он должен храниться в папке <путь к папке компилятора>\bin):

```
    REM SETTING UP MINGW-W64 ENVIRONMENT
    SET PATH=%PATH%;<путь к папке компилятора>\bin;
```

* этот файлик настраивает переменные среды

4) Создать ярлык для env.bat и поместить на рабочий стол. В свойствах ярлыка подправить путь к объекту следующим образом:

```
    C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /A /Q /K <путь к env.bat>
```

После этих 4 махинаций можно просто кликать по ярлыку на рабочем столе.

5) Запустив ярлык, переходите в открывшейся консоле в папку с распакованными исходниками Boost:

```
    CD /D "<путь к исходникам>"
```

6) Ввести:

```
    bootstrap.bat gcc
```

Да, именно опция gcc отвечает и за GCC, и за MinGW. Производится процесс сборки Boost.Build Engine.

7) Ввести:

```
    b2 toolset=gcc
```

Производится процесс сборки самого Boost. Ждать.

Для компилятора от Microsoft Visual Studio нужно расписывать?
PS: Эти собранные библиотеки гарантируют свою корректную работу только с тем компилятором, которым были собраны.